# How can I move pairs of columns into rows and create an ID at the same time?

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a bunch of raw data obtained from a software with not many optimization options.
When I convert it to `csv` and read into R, I obtain this:

[image]

As you can see, I have 2 types of variables, `Force` and `Time`, for 15 different packs of data. I want to group every data of Force and Time in only 2 columns, and create a third column with the ID of every dataset, something like this:

```
ID                     | Force| Time
------------------------------------
SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s 001 | 52.2 | 0.00
SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s 001 | 55.3 | 0.04
...                    | ...  | ...
SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s 002 | 64.8 | 0.00
SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s 002 | 69.6 | 0.04
```

I tried using tidyr function `gather()` but the results were not satisfatory.

It's the first question I make here, so my apologies if any information is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to first `gather` all your columns and then `spread` with respect to alternating `Force` and `Time` rows.

First, we recreate a small snippet of your data as:

```
rtabla1 <- structure(list(SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001.Force = c(52.2, 55.3, 62.6, 66.5, 70.8, 75.9, 77.6, 78.7, 80.2, 83.8), SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001.Time = c(0, 0.004, 0.008, 0.012, 0.016, 0.02, 0.024, 0.028, 0.032, 0.036), 
SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002.Force = c(64.8, 69.6, 76, 80.2, 85.1, 
90.5, 94.1, 95.6, 99.7, 103.4), SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002.Time = c(0, 
0.004, 0.008, 0.012, 0.016, 0.02, 0.024, 0.028, 0.032, 0.036
)), .Names = c("SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001.Force", "SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001.Time", "SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002.Force", "SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002.Time"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
##   SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001.Force SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001.Time SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002.Force SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002.Time
##1                          52.2                       0.000                         64.8                       0.000
##2                          55.3                       0.004                         69.6                       0.004
##3                          62.6                       0.008                         76.0                       0.008
##4                          66.5                       0.012                         80.2                       0.012
##5                          70.8                       0.016                         85.1                       0.016
##6                          75.9                       0.020                         90.5                       0.020
##7                          77.6                       0.024                         94.1                       0.024
##8                          78.7                       0.028                         95.6                       0.028
##9                          80.2                       0.032                         99.7                       0.032
##10                         83.8                       0.036                        103.4                       0.036
```

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
result <- rtabla1 %>% mutate(Row=seq_len(n())) %>%                             ##1.
                      gather("ID","Vals",-Row) %>%                             ##2.
                      mutate(FT=ifelse(grepl(".Force$",ID), "Force", "Time"),  ##3.
                             ID=sub("(.Force$)|(.Time$)","",ID)) %>%
                      spread(FT,Vals) %>%                                      ##4.
                      select(-Row) %>%                                         ##5.
                      arrange(ID)                                              ##6.
```

Notes:

1. First add an identifier column that is just the row numbers.
2. `gather` all the columns except `Row` resulting in an `ID` column that contains the column names that are gathered.
3. `mutate` this `ID` column using string manipulation to form the column `FT`. This `FT` column is created to identify which of the gathered rows are a `Force` and which are `Time`. It will be used in the subsequent `spread`. and its values are created to match the column names of your result (i.e., `"Force"` or `"Time"`). Here, use `grepl` to check if `ID` ends with `".Force"`. If it does, then set the `FT` column to `"Force"`; otherwise, set the `FT` column to `"Time"`. Then, update the `ID` column to remove either `".Force"` or `".Time"` from its end.
4. Now, `spread` using the `FT` as the key and the gathered values as the value.
5. Remove the `Row` column from the result.
6. Sort by `ID`

The `result` using the small snippet of data is as expected:

```
print(result)
##                       ID Force  Time
##1  SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001  52.2 0.000
##2  SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001  55.3 0.004
##3  SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001  62.6 0.008
##4  SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001  66.5 0.012
##5  SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001  70.8 0.016
##6  SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001  75.9 0.020
##7  SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001  77.6 0.024
##8  SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001  78.7 0.028
##9  SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001  80.2 0.032
##10 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.001  83.8 0.036
##11 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002  64.8 0.000
##12 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002  69.6 0.004
##13 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002  76.0 0.008
##14 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002  80.2 0.012
##15 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002  85.1 0.016
##16 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002  90.5 0.020
##17 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002  94.1 0.024
##18 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002  95.6 0.028
##19 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002  99.7 0.032
##20 SR_1.5x1.5x1.5_90s.002 103.4 0.036
```